# How to find the coefficient of $a$ in a quadratic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> If a root of the equation $$3x^2 + 4x + 12a + 9ax = 0$$ is greater than 6, then the correct statement of the coefficient $a$ is:
>
> a) $a = 2$
>
> b) $a> -2$
>
> c) $a = -2$
>
> d) $a <-2$
>
> e) $-2\le a\le 2$

What I did was solve it as if a root was exactly $6$, and I find that $a$ is equal to $2$ ... But the premise says that a root has to be greater than $6$, not equal to $6$ ... and I do not know how find that, for now I would know that $a$ does not have to be $2$ ...

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote?

Comment: @mfl I suspect it has something to do with the question being written in Spanish.

Comment: Why did you choose to write this post in Spanish? Reading your other posts it seems that you are perfectly capable of writing in English.

Comment: If $a = 2$, then the roots must be negative.  Did you mean $a = -2$?

Comment: Solve $3x^2+4x+12a+9ax = 0$ for $a$ to get $a = -\frac{x}{3}$ (note the solve step assumes $x\not= -\frac{4}{3}$ when we divide by $9x+12$, but you are next going to assume $x>6$ so this case is not a problem)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\;3x^2 + 4x + 12a + 9ax = x(3x+4)+3a(3x+4)= (x+3a)(3x+4)\,$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

\begin{align} 3x^2+4x+12a+9ax = 0&\iff 3x^2+(4+9a)x+12a= 0\\ &\iff x=\dfrac{-4-9a\pm \sqrt{(4+9a)^2-144a}}{6}.\end{align} So,

$$\dfrac{-4-9a\pm \sqrt{(4+9a)^2-144a}}{6}\ge 6 \iff -4-9a\pm \sqrt{(4+9a)^2-144a}\ge 36. $$

That is

$$-4-9a\pm \sqrt{16+72a -63a^2}\ge 36$$

So, you can check what is the correct answer.

Comment: Llego  a que $\;2a^2 + 9a + 22<0,$

Answer (score 0):

Using @dxiv hint $(x+3a)(3x+4) = 0$ we have $x = -\frac{4}{3} < 6$ and $x = -3a > 6$ Therefore, $a < -2$